# Rails SearchKick with matching on fields word_start and exact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have a model that I would like to search on with a mix of word_start and exact matches across fields.

For example:

If we have records in database with **full_name** and **email** columns:

> **Full Name, Email**
>  1 Andrew Smith, andrew@gmail.com
>  2 Alex Smith, anna@gmail.com

Expected Cases:

> 'andrew' - [1]
>  'a' - [1,2]
>  'anna@gmail' - [2]
>  'anna' -
> []

Another words, would like to **word_start** on full_name, but **exact** on email.

I have this so far, but get the following error.

employee.rb

```
searchkick callbacks: word_start: [:full_name]

def search_data
    {
        id: self.id,
        full_name: self.full_name,
        email: self.email
    }
end
```

controller

```
@results = Employee.search(
            @query,
            fields: [{"full_name" => :word_start}, {"email" => :exact}],
            misspellings: false
        )
```

Error

> "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot search on
> field [email] since it is not indexed.",

Answer (score 0):

Try to reindex Employee model and then give a try - `Employee.reindex`

Comment: Yep, I have a line above where I do that every time before I perform search for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `rake searchkick:reindex:all` to index your actual data. Everytime you change anything searchkick related on your model you may want to run that to get the latest indices.